# Can't Send Email from Mobius form

Tags: 2sxc

I'm trying to create a simple form, but not getting very far.

I deleted all the extensions etc and then reinstalled so I just had the basic setup.

I select a Contact Form, and updated the owner email. Yet it gave me an error saying sender address not specified.

Any help would be appreciated.

Screenshot 1 at https://www.screencast.com/t/PgpsPn0P8mrb
Screenshot 2 at https://www.screencast.com/t/G9cKnRN2

I couldn't find any log entries for the sending. In the DNN logs there were lots of errors with HttpClient not found from MailChimps.cs, but I'm not wanting to use MailChimp. In my previous attempt I tried removing mailchimp references from the code and still got these errors.

I like the concept, but I find the help very unhelpful, often out of date and it assumes way to much. I'm willing to persist, but I'm under time contrainsts and it may be just easier to build my own module in C#.

Comment: Is your SMTP setup in Dnn and working? What versions of Dnn, 2sxc, and Mobius?

Answer (score 0):

You can set this globally, or on each form in the normal form configuration:
[image]

Comment: I've set this up. It doesn't work.